# Каким образом сделать такой эффект футера?

Tags: css, вёрстка

подскажите пожалуйста, как добиться такого эффекта появления футера?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEjMd.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Смотреть на весь экран

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
  height: 970px;
}

main{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 10;
  background: lightgreen;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

footer{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur vel quaerat minima ut soluta ex earum ullam ipsa maxime at?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur vel quaerat minima ut soluta ex earum ullam ipsa maxime at?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur vel quaerat minima ut soluta ex earum ullam ipsa maxime at?</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur vel quaerat minima ut soluta ex earum ullam ipsa maxime at?</p>
</main>
<footer>
  Это фуутер но он фиксированный и имеет z-index меньше чем main
</footer>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
main{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

footer{
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: +, только у `position: sticky;` плохая поддержка